# Icons in menu gone in Chrome Developer tools after update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After Chrome auto-upgraded itself, the icons for the menu disappeared.

How do I re-enable them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) and in the bottom right you can click on the gear icon to bring up the settings window.

There you can enable icons again.

Comment: This option has since been removed. Goodnight, icons.

Comment: @PaulIrish Why? They were so convenient! Bring back the icons option or at least turn it off by default if it bothers you that much.

Comment: Seriously! Why can't we at least have the option to turn them on?

Comment: no, seriously.. WHY?!

Comment: Those tiny icons made me a better developer. Now what am I going to do?