# Why did the toolbar icons disappear from Google Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I use Google Chrome Developer Tools all the time. Suddenly, the toolbar icons went away. They used to be above each of `Elements`, `Resources`, etc... and now they are gone. I guess this is okay because I didn't need them in the first place. But, is there a way to turn them back on?

Comment: Posted this here because I Googled this to no avail when this happened to me a few weeks back. Finally stumbled upon Developer Tools settings and saw the option to re-enable the icons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me too the other day. It took me a while, but I finally found the spot where you can re-enable them: just go to the Developer Tools settings. Incidentally, there is a bunch of other cool stuff there, too.

To bring up the settings (I'm using version 25), click the gear icon on the bottom-right of Developer Tools window. On the left, click `General`. Under `Appearance`, you'll find a checkbox labeled `Show toolbar icons`.

Incidentally, be sure to check out the `Shortcuts` area if you like to navigate with the keyboard.

Comment: On Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m, they seem to have taken this option away! Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks that way. Update here if you find it.

Comment: @kaveman This was confirmed by Paul Irish in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167087/icons-in-menu-gone-in-chrome-developer-tools-after-update#comment-28525525). No reason given on why...